# Detecting Changes Coming Into View in Angular App and Preventing Repeated Firing of POST Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my Angular app I am passing some user-selected filter values from one component to another via Angular's event emitters. So the receiving component view looks this:

```
<data-view [records]="records"
    (sendCache)="onValuesReceived($event, type = 'location')"
    (sendOrigFile)="onValuesReceived($event, type = 'origFile')"
    (sendStart)="onValuesReceived($event, type = 'start')"
    (sendEnd)="onValuesReceived($event, type = 'end')">
</data-view>
```

I then process those filter selections coming in like this:

```
public typesProcess(value, type) {
  if (value && type) { this.filters[type] = value; }
    return this.filters;
}
```

And then save those selections within a "selections" variable in the onValuesReceived() function. This function therefore fires whenever an event is emitted into the component (that's the problem, because there are multiple event emitters, it's causing the POST request here to fire multiple times - even if the values haven't changed):

```
public onValuesReceived(value, type) {
    let selections = this.filtersService.typesProcess(value, type);

    let fn = resRecordsData => {
        this.records = resRecordsData;
        let data = resRecordsData.data;
    };

     this.filtersService.getByFilters(
        // send values;
}
```

Based on comments below, it sounds like the best option may be to gather them all and send them via one event emitter. That would solve the problem of having the API POST request firing multiple times every time one of these event emitters arrived.

Comment: No. There isn't a lifecycle hook for that. Here are the ones available: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: You have asked many questions around this the past few days with the same code. Maybe you should look at approaching this completely differently than you have. Is there a reason that your `data-view` component needs to have all of those outputs or can you just have a single one and push all of the changes at once?

Comment: It's hard to get a clear picture of your component layout from the code snippets but have you tried calling onFilterReceived() within processByTypes() method instead of returning filters.

Comment: @Muirik you can emit whatever object you want from an event (EventEmitter). It is entirely up to you.

Comment: I will look into that option then. It would solve many problems if doable. The trick will be keeping track of the type and values when passed with one event emitter.

Comment: If you could show a screenshot of how your filters are laid out, it'd be better. And I already suggested that you should gather the filters then send them as one. Catch the change event of all the filters in the Component then work logic on them, once the logic passed, emit ONE SINGLE event to the parent along with the processed-filters.

Comment: @ChauTran, as requested, I have added code from my filters component above.

Comment: How do you trigger your POST request to filter? Once you catch the event emitter, you call the POST request?

Comment: @ChauTran I updated my code to show what I was working with. The filter events are taken in by the onFilterReceived() function, which makes the POST request fire.

Answer (score 0):

Though our approach on how and when to send the Parameters to filter, I'll post my approach:

`search.component.ts`: Where my filter inputs are.

```
private triggerSelectionChange() {
    if (!this.isAtListings) {
        return;
    }
    const params = new SearchParameters();

    params.distance = this.selectedDistance;
    params.categoryName = this.categoryName;
    let geoLatLng;
    if (this.selectedLocation && Array.isArray(this.selectedLocation._geoloc)) {
        geoLatLng = this.selectedLocation._geoloc[0];
    } else {
        geoLatLng = this.selectedLocation ? this.selectedLocation._geoloc : this.latlngObj;
    }

    if (geoLatLng) {
        params.lat = geoLatLng.lat;
        params.lng = geoLatLng.lng;
    }

    params.placesId = this.selectedLocation ? this.selectedLocation.objectID : '';
    params.kidFriendly = this.kidFriendly.toString();
    params.petFriendly = this.petFriendly.toString();
    params.handicappedAccessible = this.handicappedAccessible.toString();

    this.optionsChanged.emit(params);
}

    onDistanceChange(e) {
         const distance = parseInt(e, 10);
         this.selectedDistance = isNaN(distance) ? e : distance;
         this.radius = isNaN(distance) ? 'all' : (distance * 1609);
         this.triggerSelectionChange();
    }

    onCategoryChange(e) {
         this.selectedCategory = e;
         this.categoryName = '';
         for (const cat of this.categories) {
            if (cat.name === e) {
                this.categoryName = e;
                break;
            }
        }
        this.triggerSelectionChange();
    }

    // more filters down
```

`listings.component.ts`: parent to `search.component` and where the results are displayed.

```
searchParametersChanged(params: SearchParameters) {
    this.searchParams$.next(params);
    // instead of calling another Observable like I do here, you can use the params to actually do your POST request.
}
```

The gist is to process your filters in `triggerSelectionChange()` then emit the desired value to the parent.

Comment: Added more code above, if that helps. I will take a look at your solution shortly.